# MonoAndroid : no sdk found at specified location in monoDevelop and visualStudio

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have installed MonoAndroid and monoDevelop in windows.but when I want to set android sdk locatin monoDevelop always says that "no SDK found at specified location."

The SDK is located in "C:\SDK". I also tried installing android SDK with windows installer.

EDIT: When I click on "Mono for android" in visual studio options for setting SDK path an error appear that :
 "There was an error attempting to initialize the MonoAndroidPackage:
System.ArgumentNulException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
..."

Comment: be sure to have set the sdk path correctly on monodevelop and visual studio mono for android options

Comment: thanks; I'm sure. it's correct path. as I said the SDK is located in "C:\SDK". and I set this path in monodevelop. post edited.

Comment: you could try to move your sdk location, this way you'll be able to know if that specific path is not the problem

Comment: Not works, this problem exists in any path.

Answer (score 4):

" *ensure that the android SDK tools and platform-tools are downloaded and installed. To do this open up the Android SDK Manager from the Start menu and ensure the "Status" of each of these is "Installed"* "!!!

with this solution, the problem must be solved!

[Same problem - SOLVED!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476031/there-wan-an-error-attempting-to-initialize-the-monoandroidpackage)

Answer (score 0):

I just faced with this problem and realised Java and Java SE JDK isn't installed on my PC. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: No, JDK is currently installed in my PC.