# There wan an error attempting to initialize the monoAndroidPackage

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am new in mono for android. I am download and install **mono-android-4.2.7.15330979** in my computer. When i start my visual studio 2010 then i got this error.

Here is detail about error:

```
There was an error attempting to initialize the MonoAndroidPackage 
System.ArgumentNullException: Vale cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
         At System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1,String path2)
         At Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidSdk.get.AdbExe()
         At Mono.Android.VisualStudio.MonoAndrioidDeviceManager.ctor()
         At Mono.Android.VisualStudio.MonoAndrioidSdk.get_DeviceManager()
         At Mono.Android.VisualStudio. MonoAndrioidPackage.Initialize()
```

And when i try to create a Project then get following error

```
 This project file 
 ‘Project Path’ cannot be opened
 The project type is not supported by this installation
```

I am also install

```
  Java at "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02"
  Set environment variable JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02"
  Android SDK at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

I am using :

```
Windows7 64 bit
Visual Studio 2010 ultimate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to update the location of the Android SDK in your Mono for Android/Xamarin.Android settings under Visual Studio (TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> Xamarin.Android)

Ensure the path is correct as the exception is being thrown when combining the path to the adb.exe file.

[image: Mono for Android settings]

**Update**

The problem in this case was the fact that the platform-tools were not installed.

Comment: When i go to TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> Mono For Android it`s show me this error messages. "An error occurred loading this property page"

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Mono for Android?

Comment: @Hasan009 Also ensure that the android SDK tools and platform-tools are downloaded and installed. To do this open up the Android SDK Manager from the Start menu and ensure the "Status" of each of these is "Installed"

Comment: After installing platform-tools and Android API Level 8 my problem is sloved

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that worked for me.

Start -> Run -> regedit

HKLM -> Software -> Novell -> Mono for Android

Check if AndroidSdkDirectory is correct.

Answer (score 1):

this is problem is simple ,,,
you should open MonoDelop ,and to set option these JDK and ADM install directory, exit MonoDelop, reopen your  visual studio 2010 .